# Unity3D 2017.1 как сделать Tap с первого раза

Tags: unity3d, touch, multi-touch

День добрый. 
Работаю в Unity3D версия 2017.1 под Windows 7, но на сколько могу судить подобное поведение присутствует и в 5 версии.

Делаем интерактивный стол, на котором катаем фигурки по столу. Пытаюсь поймать катящийся по столу предмет пальцем. Для этого по задумке надо на него нажать. Но когда я опускаю на тачскрин первый палец, если его не двигать то касание не опознается до момента пока не оторвешь палец от экрана, либо пока не сдвинешь его хоть немного по экрану, либо пока не появится другое касание. Все остальные касания определяются в момент соприкосновения с экраном сразу. То есть если уже прижать где то палец к тачскину и при этом в другой части экрана ловить объект то он ловится как и ожидается.

Пробовал отключать `Input.simulateMouseWithTouches`, эффекта не дает.

В чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на форуме http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/164084/touch-screen-inputdown-detection-problems.html

Надо открыть жесты Windows и сделать небольшие настройки. Нам требуется отключить жест "Нажатие и удержание - Правый щелчок".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем жест и нажимаем кнопку параметры. В открывшемся окне выключить галочку "Использовать нажатие и удерживание как правый щелчок":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого касание будет срабатывать сразу.